# Removing unused memory from an array so it doesnt output random numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, string, memory

```
void dealCard(int tds, int totaldeck[]) //take total deck divide it by two deal it to two player
{

    int ku=0; //ku is the increasing card number so for 1 you give it to p1 then 2 u give to p2
    int player1deck[tds/2];
    int player2deck[tds/2];
    int num =0;
    int num1=0;

    for (ku; ku < tds; ku++)
    {
        if (ku % 2 == 1) // every other card is given to playerdeck1
        {
            player1deck[num] = totaldeck[ku]; //totaldeck is the already shuffled complete deck
            num++;
            //cout << tds << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            player2deck[num1] = totaldeck[ku];
            num1++;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int kookoo = 0; kookoo < ku; kookoo++)
    {
    cout << player1deck[kookoo] << endl;
    }
}
```

I am creating a function that deals half a deck of already shuffled cards to both player1 and player 2.

An issue im having is that once all 26 parameters are filled up in player1deck[num]. the outputs become random numbers like 52, 10201328, -208476711, 0, 1, etc. I think the computer is just trying to allocate memory to unfilled spots because [ku] goes all the way up to tds (amount of decks the user is playing with * 52) and [num] is only half of that. Is there anyway to get rid of this extra memory, so I can get rid of those random numbers? thank you very much for any help/suggesstions

Comment: When printing out the cards, you should not count to `ku` since these are the total number of cards, but player 1 only has half of them.

Comment: -1, why would you remove all your code from the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`player1deck` only contains 26 elements, and the last loop is trying to access elements beyond the first 26. This is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to change the loop condition like so:

```
for (int kookoo = 0; kookoo < tds / 2; kookoo++)
```

Comment: oh that makes complete sense, i thought the error was in my if statement. just to double check, based on my code, the values allocated to each string is accurate right?